# First WPF animation then run the code in Screen ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Hello I have a question I want to do this animation then when the animation is completed I would like to run the code and I can't figure it out the way to do it in MVVM using CaliburnMicro.

Please help me if possible.

```
    <Button x:Name="Forgot">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform />
        </Button.RenderTransform>

        <Button.Triggers>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UserName"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                         From="0" To="-1000" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Password"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                         From="0" To="-1000" Duration="0:0:1"  />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LogIn"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                         From="0" To="-1000" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Forgot"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                         From="0" To="-1000" Duration="0:0:1"  />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the [`Completed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed?view=netcore-3.1) event a `StoryBoard` raises once the animations finishes.

You can either use an `EventTrigger` for that (though I am not certain if that will work) or bind a handler in XAML and do whatever you like at that point.

Update:

XAML:

```
<Storyboard Completed="storyboard_Completed">
     ...
```

C#:

```
void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
      // Do whatever you want here.
}
```

Comment: This is the problem, I don't know how to do this. If I do `Completed="Forgot `  then I get error. Is it possible to show the example?

Comment: I can do this:   `public partial class LoginView : UserControl
    {
        private IEventAggregator _events;
        public LoginView(IEventAggregator events)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _events.PublishOnUIThread(new ResetEvent());
        }
    }` but then I get error in Bootstraper

Comment: Or in other words I don't know how to post then the Event so ViewModel can subscribe to it.

Comment: Or should this storyboard_Completed be in ViewModel

Comment: What matters is that you helped me did what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

```
    private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginViewModel vm = this.DataContext as LoginViewModel;

        vm.Forgot();
    }
```

and now it works. thank you